# Error on componentDidMount(), undefined is not a function

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

I am using redux in react native. And I am trying to access https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com with axios.
This is the code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View,Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {getArticles} from '../Articles';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class Articles extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getArticles()
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Articles</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        articles:state.articles
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({getArticles},dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Articles)
```

And this is action where I want to access that link with axios:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

export function getArticles(){
    const request = axios.get(`${URL}/post`).then(response => response.data)

    return{
        type:"GET_ARTICLES",
        payload: request,
    }
}
```

This is screenshot of an error:
[image: Error image]

I am new to this so maybe I did some dumb mistake.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(getArticles())
}
```

or import store to the Component and

```
componentDidMount(){
    store.dispatch(getArticles())
}
```

Comment: this.props.dispatch(getArticles()), worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to pass `getArticles` as a prop? Just use:

```
componentDidMount(){
    getArticles()
}
```

Comment: It still says its undefined